# Melhor forma de implementar DataAnnotations

Tags: c#, sintaxe, atributos

Existe alguma diferença nas seguintes implementações?

```
 [Required, StringLength(150, ErrorMessage = "Insira no máximo 150 caracteres")]
 [Index(IsUnique =true)]
 public int MyProperty { get; set; }

 [Required]
 [StringLength(150, ErrorMessage ="Insira no máximo 150 caracteres")]
 [Index(IsUnique =true)]
 public int MyProperty { get; set; }
```

Pergunto afim de saber, se tem momentos que se usa do primeiro jeito e em outros do segundo. Ou é a mesma coisa ?

Comment: Você quer dizer, em linhas separadas ou juntas?

Comment: @bigown, isso. Se uso o `Required` na mesma linha que o `StringLength` ou em linhas diferentes, como sempre vejo por aí.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Só pra constar, a resposta é válida pra todos os tipos de *attributes* e não somente **`DataAnnotations`**.

#### Não há nenhuma diferença funcional entre as duas declarações.

É mais questão de gosto de "estilo" de programar.

Na maioria das vezes, **eu** prefiro usar os *attributes* na mesma linha, a não ser que eles tenham nomes muito grandes ou eu acabe usando muitos parâmetros, aí deixo em linhas separadas para facilitar a leitura.

Então:

```
[PrimeiroAtributo, SegundoAtributo]
public string Nome { get; set; }
```

É exatamente a mesma coisa que

```
[PrimeiroAtributo]
[SegundoAtributo]
public string Nome { get; set; }
```

Comment: quando a @AngélicaFlausino diz: 
Se você deixar somente assim:
"`[Required, StringLength(150, ErrorMessage = "Insira no máximo 150 caracteres")]`
A mensagem customizada vai disparar somente para a string com o tamanho máximo de 150 caracteres. E assim será a mesma coisa"

Ela quis dizer que somente o _Attribute_ `StringLength` funcionará, essa informação não procede então  ?

Comment: Eu não tenho como falar sobre o que ela quis dizer. Mas posso te afirmar com toda certeza que a minha resposta está certa. Eu acho que ela quis dizer a mesma coisa que eu, só que acabou se enrolando um pouco e falando demais, por isso decidi postar a minha resposta, pra ter algo mais direto e sucinto.

Answer (score 3):

Se você deixar somente assim:

```
[Required, StringLength(150, ErrorMessage = "Insira no máximo 150 caracteres")]
```

A mensagem customizada vai disparar somente para a string com o tamanho máximo de 150 caracteres. E assim será a mesma coisa

```
[Required]
[StringLength(150, ErrorMessage ="Insira no máximo 150 caracteres")]
```

Se estiver utilizando o jquery validate será emitido uma mensagem padrão para o Required, mas se você quiser deixar a mensagem customizada:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "O campo xxx deverá ser preenchido!)]
```

E creio que a melhor maneira é utilizar assim como no exemplo:

```
public class Produto
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Digite o nome do produto."), Column(Order = 1)]
    [MinLength(5, ErrorMessage = "O tamanho mínimo do nome são 5 caracteres.")]
    [StringLength(200, ErrorMessage = "O tamanho máximo são 200 caracteres.")]
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Quantidade")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:n2}",
            ApplyFormatInEditMode = true,
            NullDisplayText = "Estoque vazio")]
    [Range(10, 25, ErrorMessage = "A Qtde deverá ser entre 10 e 25.")]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    public double Qtde { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:n2}",
            ApplyFormatInEditMode = true,
            NullDisplayText = "Sem preço")]
    [Range(3, 500, ErrorMessage = "O preço deverá ser entre 3 e 500.")]
    [Column(Order = 3)]
    public decimal Preco { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
    [Column(Order = 4)]
    [Display(Name="Vencimento")]
    public DateTime Dt_Vencto { get; set; }
}
```